# C table initialisation

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-warnings

I want to intialise a table that should contain a few chars for comparing it to values later, this is my code:

```
 char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
```

I get a bunch of error messages from the compiler though, some are:

```
dn08.c: In function ‘main’:

dn08.c:16:37: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};      
                                   ^
dn08.c:16:5: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
     ^
 dn08.c:16:43: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘:’ token
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                           ^
 dn08.c:16:44: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                            ^
 dn08.c:16:49: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                 ^
 dn08.c:16:54: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                      ^
 dn08.c:16:59: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                           ^
 dn08.c:16:63: error: stray ‘#’ in program
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                               ^
 dn08.c:16:64: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                                ^
 dn08.c:16:68: error: stray ‘@’ in program
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                                    ^
 dn08.c:16:69: warning: missing terminating ' character
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                                                     ^
 dn08.c:16:43: error: missing terminating ' character
     unsigned char z[8] = {' ', '.', '\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
                                           ^
 dn08.c:51:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ at end of input
 }
 ^
dn08.c:51:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Comment: You added 9 chars to a 8 char array

Comment: If this is strictly a look-up table, it should be made `const`. That will prevent you from accidentally changing it, and make it clearer to humans that the data is read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try escaping the backslash

```
 char z[] = {' ', '.', '\\', ':', 'o', '&', '8', '#', '@'};
```

These two backslashes at `z[2]` will be treated as one backslash while only one backslash in your code messes everything up.

You also don't really need to specify the array length as it'll be auto-calculated for you by the compiler.

Comment: "_The array length_", which is wrong in the original code.

Comment: @iharob, that's why I suggested to remove it.